# Flutter Image.asset file cache

Tags: flutter, image, caching

Just basic Flutter app.

```
Center(
  child: Image.asset('assets/img1.jpg')
)
```

Everything works fine, as long as I try to change the image. The image in the application remains old. Neither "Hot Reboot" nor "Hot Restart" helps, only stopping and launching the application.

The same situation when I add second image, app always crashes with an error (image not found, or bad image codec) until I restart it.

```
Center(
  Column(children: [
     Image.asset('assets/img1.jpg'),
     Image.asset('assets/img2.jpg'),
  ])
)
```

Is this normal behavior?

```
Flutter (stable channel, 3.0.5, in Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889])
[√] Android toolchain - development for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0)
[√] Chrome - development for the Internet
[√] Visual Studio - Development for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run ```flutter clean``` in terminal?

Comment: flutter clean helps to clear cache, but it does "cold restart" app. So, it doesn't help.

Comment: I hope someone can provide a more detailed explanation, but I think that behind the scenes Flutter still caches the images in a special archive object called the *asset bundle*.  I was able to recreate your problem and I resolved it by going to the pubspec.yaml file and explicitly saving it. I know that is the same as just running ```flutter pub get``` but running it through the terminal didn't work for me. I had to go to the actual file and save then hot reload worked fine after that. I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, saving this file didn't help in any way.  Flutter still cannot find new images in assets without stopping the application.

Comment: Only other thing I can suggest is explicitly including the path to the new image file rather than the asset directory in the pubspec. So for example along with "assets/" to also have "assets/img2.jpg" then after the hot reload you can delete this. This also worked for me.